# Action of modular group on complex upper half plane. Quotient space is $P^{1}$. [Reference request]

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma$ denote the modular group $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

We define $\Gamma(N)$ to be the kernel of following natural map
$$PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$$

Now, 
$$\Gamma(1)=PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$$

Let $X(N)$ demote the quotient of complex upper half plane under the action of $\Gamma(1)$.

Is it correct that $X(1) $ is isomorphic $P^{1}$ ?

If yes, kindly mention the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [$j$-invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant) is a $\Gamma$ invariant holomorphic and surjective map from $\mathbb H\to\mathbb C$, and descends to a holomorphic bijection
$$j:X(1)\to\mathbb C$$

which has a pole at infinity.

As you've defined $X(1)$ (which is usually denoted $Y(1)$), it is clear that it is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ for the simple reason that it is not compact - it has a "cusp" at infinity.

However, $\Gamma(N)$ acts on $\mathbb H^* = \mathbb H\cup\mathbb P^1(\mathbb Q)$. Letting $$X(N) :=\Gamma(N)\backslash \mathbb H^*,$$$X(N)$ is now compact, and
the $j$-invariant becomes a holomorphic bijection $X(1)\to\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ with holomorphic inverse. In particular, $X(1)\cong\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ as Riemann surfaces.